# Match token and it's context with possible overlapping

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm processing some text files and want to find certain tokens and also some of the text sorrounding them to get some context.
My problem is that I can't find every instance of the tokens if they are close enough to get captured by the context of a token preceding it.

As an example and simplification, let's say I want to find every 5-digit number in some text, and also 20 characters before and after it to get some context.

First I tried something like:

```
<?php
$text = "Lorem ipsum 11111 dolor sit 22222 amet, consectetur 33333 adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 1111 incididunt ut 11111 labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
$nmbrs_tmp = array();
preg_match_all("@.{0,19}[^\d](\d{5})[^\d].{0,19}@s", $text, $nmbrs_tmp);
print_r($nmbrs_tmp);
```

But it won't capture the 22222 because it's already within the first capture of 11111 and it's context:

```
//output
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem ipsum 11111 dolor sit 22222 ame
            [1] => t, consectetur 33333 adipiscing elit, se
            [2] =>  1111 incididunt ut 11111 labore et dolore ma
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11111
            [1] => 33333
            [2] => 11111
        )

)
```

Then I tried with lookaheads and lookbehinds but 1st: lookbehinds must be fixed length, and 2nd: I won't capture the context anymore: `"@(?<=.{0,19})[^\d](\d{5})[^\d](?=.{0,19})@s" //this won't work`

Ideally, I would love something like this, where I capture every instance of 5-digit numbers, and also get all possible context:

```
//output
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Lorem ipsum 11111 dolor sit 22222 ame
            [1] => sum 11111 dolor sit 22222 amet, consectetur 3
            [2] => 2 amet, consectetur 33333 adipiscing elit, se
            [3] =>  1111 incididunt ut 11111 labore et dolore ma
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11111
            [1] => 22222
            [2] => 33333
            [3] => 11111
        )

)
```

If there's just no way to do this with a regex, then I'm open to PHP solutions that involve going through the text multiple times or using more regexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a method using match offsets to calculate relevant substrings:

```
<?php
$text = "99999 Lorem ipsum 11111 dolor sit 22222 amet, consectetur 33333 adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor 1111 incididunt ut 11111 labore et dolore magna aliqua. 99999";
$nmbrs_tmp = array();
preg_match_all("@\b\d{5}\b@s", $text, $nmbrs_tmp, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

foreach ($nmbrs_tmp[0] as $key => $field) {
    $offset = $field[1];
    $start = ( $offset>=20 ? $offset-20 : 0 );
    $length = $offset>=20 ? 45 : 45-(20-$offset);
    $nmbrs_tmp[0][$key][2] = substr( $text, $start, $length );
}

print_r($nmbrs_tmp);
```

First we simplify the regex to just find 5-digit numbers (your original regex would miss numbers at the beginning and end of the line).

Then we match, passing the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE flag.

Finally we use the returned offset to calculate the length of the desired substring (it probably doesn't matter if `$length` falls off the end of the input but you can adjust it if you care).

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 99999
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 99999 Lorem ipsum 11111 d
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11111
                    [1] => 18
                    [2] => 99999 Lorem ipsum 11111 dolor sit 22222 ame
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 22222
                    [1] => 34
                    [2] => sum 11111 dolor sit 22222 amet, consectetur 3
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 33333
                    [1] => 58
                    [2] => 2 amet, consectetur 33333 adipiscing elit, se
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 11111
                    [1] => 122
                    [2] =>  1111 incididunt ut 11111 labore et dolore ma
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 99999
                    [1] => 159
                    [2] => olore magna aliqua. 99999
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Ok, this is an interesting solution, thank you! I'll adapt it to some extent.  I didn't think about the beginning and end of the line cases, thank you about that. I don't use \b boundaries because I actually don't want to match the token if it's preceded or followed by certain characters. Let's say I don't want to grab those 5-digit numbers if they have `$`, `/` or `#` right before them. Can you still distinguish the beginning and end of string cases easily?

Comment: You could use lookahead/lookbehind. Or something more verbose like: `(?:^|[^\d$/#])(\d{5})(?:$|[^\d])` - and then work with `$nmbrs_tmp[1]`